# run multiple links with one script without open pages

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, cron

when i open this page `pronostico_match.php?fixtureid=<?php echo $item['matchid'];?>`
this run all script inside and give me the page with all statistics by soccer match, then insert data into mysql db.

now i need to send multiple page with one click for each matchid without open all pages, i would like to run in background if possibile

i tried this below, but open like 40 links.
anyway i need to run this on background like cronjob
HTML

```
<ul class="links">
<li><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/"></a></li>
</ul>

<a id="open-all" href="#">OPEN ALL</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() { // On DOM content ready...
    var hrefs = [];

    $('.links a').each(function() {
        hrefs.push(this.href); // Store the URLs from the links...
    });

    $('#open-all').click(function() {
        for (var i in hrefs) {
            window.open(hrefs[i]); // ...that opens each stored link in its own window when clicked...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered an engine like Node.js or Deno?

Comment: unfortunately no because i don't know programming in node or deno.
can you show some example?

Comment: You can open your favorite search engine and look for "nodejs examples" or "deno examples"

Comment: You _could_ just place a couple of iframes into your document, each having one of those URLs set as `src` ... then the browser will load them automatically, without you having to click or trigger anything. Of course that comes nowhere near to an _actual_ proper cron implementation; whether such a basic approach is enough, depends on specifics we have not been given yet. (When/how often/with what level of precision regarding the timing does this need to run, how tragic would it be if one of those requests would fail occasionally, etc.)